# Am Unable to pass the value from Child to Parent component(FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT) in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to build an E-Commerce website with ReactJS(Without any backend or server).

Totally I have 4 components:

1. Navbar.jsx
2. Home.jsx
3. Products.jsx
4. Cart.jsx

**what i want is, when user clicks on **ADD TO CART** button in products.jsx, cart number should be displayed on Navbar top right corner but its not displaying.

what i tryed: i just passed props from Products.jsx page to Navbar.jsx but its not working. i tried lot but am unable to do it.. please help me...Thanks in Advance

[am familiar with functional components only]**

**CODE : Navbar.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function Navbar(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="d-flex bg-primary flex-row justify-content-between text-light ">
                <div className="left d-flex">
                        <li className="my-2"><Link className="text-light p-3 py-2" to="/">HOME</Link></li>
                        <li className="my-2"><Link className="text-light p-3 py-2" to="/products">PRODUCTS</Link></li>
                        <li className="my-2"><Link className="text-light p-3 py-2" to="/cart">CART</Link></li>
                </div>
                <div className="right">
                    <p>CART is:</p><p className="mx-2 h3">{props.text}</p> 
                        {/* I WANT TO DISPLAY THE CART ABOVE HERE */}
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

**CODE : Products.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Router from '../Router';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
function Products() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>PRODUCTS</h1>
            <button className="btn btn-success">ADD TO CART</button>
            {/* WHEN I CLICK ON ADD TO CART, CART NUMBER SHOULD UPDATED IN NAVBAR */}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Products
```

**CODE : Router.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";
  import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Products from './components/Products';
import Cart from './components/Cart';
function router() {
    return (
        <>
        <BrowserRouter>
        {/* <Navbar text="3"/> */}
        <Navbar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path='/cart' component={Cart}/>
          <Route exact path="/products" component={Products}/>
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </>  
    )
}
export default router
```

**CODE : index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Products from './components/Products';
import './index.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Router from './Router';
ReactDOM.render(

  <Router />
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**FOLDER STRUCTURE:**
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ujp.jpg)

PLEASE HELP ME...THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Router.jsx, you need to have a state to store cart number
2. pass this state value as a prop to Navbar.jsx, when this state update, Navbar prop would be update, too
3. pass setState callback as a prop to Products.jsx, when click "Add To Cart", call this callback, then state value will be updated

Router.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";
function Router() {
  // a state to store cart number
  const [text, setText] = useState(3);
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <!-- pass state value as a prop to Navbar -->
        <Navbar text={text} />
        {/* <Navbar /> */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
          <!-- pass setText callback as a prop to Products -->
          <Route
            exact
            path="/products"
            component={() => <Products setText={setText} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
export default Router;
```

Products.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Router from "../Router";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
function Products(props) {
  const { setText } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>PRODUCTS</h1>
      <!-- when button click, call setText to update text state -->
      <button
        className="btn btn-success"
        onClick={() => {
          setText((prev) => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        ADD TO CART
      </button>
      {/* WHEN I CLICK ON ADD TO CART, CART NUMBER SHOULD UPDATED IN NAVBAR */}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Products;
```

Comment: sir, Can you suggest any site or other, so i can able to learn about these prop.s because am curious about it.

Comment: I think you can check the official website: <https://reactjs.org/> There are Docs and Tutorials including the concepts of props and state.

Answer (score 0):

What you must do is transfer the value to display in the cart from the Products page to the navbar, on button click.

Both Navbar and Products components have a shared parent; Router.jsx. This means your value has to go from Navbar.jsx, up to a state in Router.jsx via a "callback". The state will then be given as the prop to the Navbar.

Following that approach will allow you to dynamically update. To summize; All you need is 1 state in Router, and 1 callback as prob in Navbar, which updates the state in Router.